# NetLogo update list when a new agent is born

Tags: list, updates, netlogo

I am barely starting to use netlogo, and I created a model in which my agents have a list referencing a unique value for all (so its length is equal to the number of agents present at time t and the item 1 in the list corresponds to the value of turtle 1). I don’t manage to update the list when a new agent is born. How can I do that?

Regards

Comment: I have a difficulty in understanding your point. Can you please post your (partial) code and ask more specific than textual description?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
turtles-own [listOfTurtleVals val]

to init-turtle
  set val random-float 1 ;just for illustration
  set listOfTurtleVals ([val] of other turtles)
end
```

Then just run `init-turtle` on each turtle you create.

Alteratively you might have meant this:

```
globals [listOfInitialVals]
turtles-own [val]
to init-turtle
  set val random-float 1 ;just for illustration
  set listOfTurtleVals (lput val listOfInitialVals)
end
```